# When trying to make a fluid simulation, my domain cube changes into an odd shape

Tags: fluid-simulation

When trying to make a fluid simulation, my domain cube changes into an odd shape. When I select 'domain' from the drop-down box, it immediately changes into an odd roundish shape. I have restarted blender and the problem is still there. When I turn fluid off, it changes back into a cube. Any help on how to fix this?

Comment: The domain mesh will be the cached fluid mesh, different on every frame just as it is simulated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! The domain gets the form of the fluid it bakes, so if *that* is what you ask then it's not a problem. If you think something still is wrong please make some screenshots of your situation and post them here.

Comment: Go to the folder where you have saved your blend file and delete the cache_fluid folder if it exists